# Overriding functions in javascript is not working, debugger skips my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify an application by overriding certain functions. I cannot release the code due to enterprise ownership. My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mylink.scriptX.js"></script>
// Some other scripts and css references
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
form_script = my_script =
{
  initialization:function (mode, json_data) {
this.parent_class.initialization(mode, json_data);
//Mycode to override the functions in scriptX.js is below:

    var x= {};
    function inherit(x) {
      var y= {};
    y.prototype = x;
    return y;
};

    (function ($) {
    var OverrideFunctions = inherit($.my_methods);
    OverrideFunctions.function1 = function () { ...};
    OverrideFunctions.function2 = function () { ...};
    OverrideFunctions.function3 = function () { ...}

})(jQuery);
} 
//some original code here
}
</script>

//some other code here
</body>
</html>
```

Now the content of the scriptX.js is something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    var my_methods = {
    function1 = function () { ...};
    function2 = function () { ...};
    function3 = function () { ...}
}
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that, I am noticing that the debugger skips the whole block of code since `OverrideFunctions.function1 = function () {` to the end `})(jQuery);` 
So my functions are not being executed and thus the application is not changed. I was wondering if that could be related

Comment: Where do you create `$.my_methods`?

Comment: Where do you invoke `my_script.initialization`, apart from inside that method?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm : I didnt create it. I am supposed to invoke my_methods that I have in scriptX, but I am not sure I am invoking it correctly since it's a local variable to the function($) { }. If what I did is wrong, how can I override those functions correctly? Thanks

Comment: @userZZZ If that object is local and not exported in some way, it's in effect private and its functions can't be overridden from outside.

Comment: @trincot from an index page. It's a very long code and that's something I didnt touch in the original application. also I dont have access to. i was just told that I can do any modification I need through that initialization method.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm All i have is a javascript and html editors to modify the "widget" and I was told I can override the functions from the initialization function. I am just an intern and still trying to learn jQuery and javascript. Can you please enlighten me on all the possible ways I can override those functions. because all I have it's what I cited above.

Comment: Also, (i know this isnt related to my original error). But the other way i could modify the functions is by replacing the whole script scriptX.js to my new updated version scriptX2.js . I did host it on github and then coppied the development link form rawgit. but it gives me this error: Refused to execute script from 'https://rawgit.com/zinebh/myfolder/master/scriptX2?_=xxxxxx' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. (i modified the link because of the property restrictions)